# Update numbers in the middle of a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking at diff-style output, but I need to update the line numbers.  So I see:

```
*** 1,2 *****
Actual line 1
Actual line 2
--- 1,2 -----
Expected line 1
Expected line 2
```

and in my results file, I'm at resline.  So if resline=line 90, I'd want to change the second "1,2" to "91,92".

In perl, I'd use the following on the line that begins "---"

```
s/(\d+?)/($1+$resline)/eg
```

How should I do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `re.sub` and pass in a callable instead of a string as the replacement:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\d+?', lambda m: str(int(m.group(0))+resline), YOUR_STR)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Why do you use a group in the re?   Wouldn't `re.sub(r'\d+?', lambda m: str(int(m.group(0))+resline), YOUR_STR)` work as well?

Comment: Yep, that works just as well. I was just translating on autopilot =). Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: "pass in a callable instead of a string as the replacement". Well huh, I never realized you could do that.